# Algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$ implies algebraic of degree at most $n$ over $F(a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $a, b$ in the field $K$ are algebraic over the subfield $F \subseteq K$. Suppose $a$ is algebraic of degree $m$ over $F$ and $b$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$. Let $F(a)$ be the field obtained by adjoining $a$ to $F$.

My question is, is it true that $b$ is algebraic of degree *at most* $n$ over $F(a)$? If so, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$, then there is a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ with coefficients in $F$ such that $P(b) = 0$. This polynomial has coefficients in $F$, but it also has coefficients in $F(a)$, so we have that $b$ is algebraic of degree at most $n$ in $F(a)$.

Comment: I see, silly me! I did think of that but I forgot that the definition of algebraic of degree $n$ means that no smaller degree works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Call $f$ the minimal polynomial of $b$ in $F$. Then, $f(b)=0$ and $f$ is in $F(a)[X]$. So the minimal polynomial of $b$ in $F(a)$ divides $f$, so it must have degree $\leq n$.